# in spite of him/his

Tags: personal-pronouns

> Jane told Marcos that in spite of (him/his) being small, he would definitely be a great asset to the team because of his athletic abilities.

In the above sentence, which of him/his is correct and why ?

Answer (score 5):

Both are grammatical, but each has a slightly different emphasis. The personal pronoun (*him*) foregrounds the fact that it was he, rather than anyone else, who was small. The possessive determiner (*his*) foregrounds the state of being small.

Answer (score 4):

Either would be accepted in most casual speech, but "his" is more formally correct.  "Being small" is a property he has, so is most properly attributed to him using a possessive.

The form using "him" is somewhat broken because it's using an objective pronoun in a subject-like capacity.